# Report Viewer memory leak

Tags: memory, reportviewer

i using reportviewer v.10.0.0.0, runtime v2.0.50727. when i fill about  1 million records, memory being up to 2G or than. 
It very bad, and if you know solution how to fix it, pls tell me know.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's just that it's not designed well. E.g. there would be large object heap fragmentation.

GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode